# Picker view displaying and populated correctly but not interactive

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface, uipickerview

I have created a Picker view in objective C and populated it with an NSArray and that all works fine, it compiles and shows on screen but the picker doesn't do anything. I'd like to turn as the user drags their finger across like you'd expect but it doesn't react in anyway.

'lil Help?

The code I used for the picker comes from "Beginning iPhone Development" but I have more views (a map view and a view I use for drawing) on screen, for clarity I can just dump all the code in here so I'll limit it to what I believe is relevant.

```
//  SingleComponentPickerViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface SingleComponentPickerViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {
    IBOutlet    UIPickerView *singlePicker;
                NSArray *pickerData;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPickerView *singlePicker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *pickerData;
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
@end


//  SingleComponentPickerViewController.m

#import "SingleComponentPickerViewController.h"

@implementation SingleComponentPickerViewController
@synthesize singlePicker;
@synthesize pickerData;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger row = [singlePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSString *selected = [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You selected %@!", selected];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:@"Thank you for choosing." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"You're Welcome" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [title release];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Luke", @"Leia", @"Han", @"Chewbacca", @"Artoo", @"Threepio", @"Lando", nil];
    self.pickerData = array;
    [array release];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [singlePicker release];
    [pickerData release];
    [super dealloc];
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Picker Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [pickerData count];
}
#pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}
@end
```

That's the code but I have a feeling the problem is more to do with how the views are placed/interacting.

Comment: Code?  Seeing how you were creating it would assist anyone trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the "useractionEnabled" property set to true (in either IB or code)?  This should be the default.

But as mentioned above in the comments ... some code might be helpful :)